# Uniformly permutation and the length of a size biased cycle

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

The cycle containing $1$ of a uniform permutation has length which is uniformly distributed. I was wondering if the converse is true:

> Suppose $\sigma$ is a permutation on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and let $u \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ be a uniformly chosen random variable, independent of $\sigma$. Let $V$ be the size of the cycle of $\sigma$ containing $u$. If $V$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ then is it true that $\sigma$ must be a uniform permutation?

Comment: It seems to me that there are $n!$ variables -- the probabilities for each permutation -- but only $n^2+1$ equations.  So for large $n$, surely this is false?  (Of course the probabilities have to be non-negative ...)

Comment: @Lucia: That indicates a more stringent condition, that for any $u$, the size of the cycle containing $u$ is uniformly distributed, is also not enough to guarantee a uniform distribution. As an example, take then uniform distribution on $S_n$, then map each permutation to the lexicographically first permutation in its conjugacy class, then conjugate by a uniformly random power of $(1 2 ... n)$. For $n \ge 3$ this is not uniformly distributed on $S_n$ but for each $u$, the cycle containing $u$ has a uniformly distributed length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that the distribution of $V|\sigma$ depends only on the lengths of the cycles in $\sigma$. Therefore, the distribution of $V$ does not change if we replace the random variable $\sigma$ with $f(\sigma)$, where $f:S_n\to S_n$ is any function that maintains the lengths of the cycles.

Example: let $\sigma$ be the identity permutation with probability $1/6$, $(12)$ with probability $3/6$, and $(123)$ with probability $2/6$.